# Scenarios andsSteps "get last change" problem

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I have following table abstracting some scenarios and their steps ordered by START_DATE "desc".

| SCENARIO_KEY | STEP_KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE | PREVIOUS_SCENARIO_KEY | PREVIOUS_STEP_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | 44 | 20xx04x4 | 0 | 120 | 44 |
| **120** | *44* | **20xx03x3** | 20xx04x4 | 120 | 38 |
| 120 | 38 | 20xx11x0 | 20xx03x3 | 121 | 38 |
| 121 | 38 | 20xx07x2 | 20xx11x0 | 120 | 44 |
| 120 | 44 | 20xx07x1 | 20xx07x2 | 120 | 38 |

I need to get first scenario_key (or another identifier) after last change to step with value 44 (step_key = 44).

So the result of this query should be some identifier of the last change - START_DATE of the first row with value 44 after last change (20xx03x3) or SCENARIO_KEY after last change (120).

In short, I need to be able to identify the line of last change to "44" step key.

Is there any analytical function (or another query) to achieve this? Can you advice?

Comment: If you have `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` columns then please give them values that are valid `DATE` data types rather than what appears to be a confusing attempt to mask some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you can get the earliest 44 date after the last non-44 date using:

```
select min(start_date)
from t
where t.start_date > (select max(t2.start_date)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.step_key <> 44
                     );
```

I think this is what you are asking for.

You can use window functions too.  Assuming that the most recent row is "44":

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by start_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by step_key order by start_date) as seqnum_sk
      from t
     ) t
where step_key = 44 and seqnum = seqnum_sk
order by start_date
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working. But I am using it in quite big select and it is inefficient. Is there any way, how to do it as analytic funcion? Maybe with using "previous_xyz_key" columns?

Comment: could you help?

Comment: @MartinFedyFedorko . . . Did you see the answer?  This answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to find the earliest row of the latest set of contiguous rows with a `STEP_KEY` value of `44`:

```sql
SELECT SCENARIO_KEY,
       STEP_KEY,
       START_DATE,
       END_DATE,
       PREVIOUS_SCENARIO_KEY,
       PREVIOUS_STEP_KEY
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY start_date DESC
  MEASURES
    match_number() AS mno,
    classifier() AS cls
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( sk44_1* sk44_2 )
  DEFINE
    sk44_1 AS step_key = 44,
    sk44_2 AS step_key = 44
)
WHERE  mno = 1
AND    cls = 'SK44_2'
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  SCENARIO_KEY,
  STEP_KEY,
  START_DATE,
  END_DATE,
  PREVIOUS_SCENARIO_KEY,
  PREVIOUS_STEP_KEY
) AS
SELECT 128, 44, DATE '2021-04-04', NULL, 120, 44 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120, 44, DATE '2021-03-13', DATE '2021-04-04', 120, 38 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120, 38, DATE '2020-11-10', DATE '2021-03-13', 121, 38 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 38, DATE '2020-07-22', DATE '2020-11-10', 120, 44 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 120, 44, DATE '2021-07-01', DATE '2020-07-22', 120, 38 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SCENARIO_KEY | STEP_KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE | PREVIOUS_SCENARIO_KEY | PREVIOUS_STEP_KEY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 120 | 44 | 13-MAR-21 | 04-APR-21 | 120 | 38 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=48c02b7eeaa5c43d8e0f551351fc23d0)*